# NSTask get the output of a command

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to run an executable on `OS X` from one of the other application.

```
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.arguments = @[@"param1", @"param2", @"param3", @"param4"];
task.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/myApp";
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];

NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
NSData *output = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[file closeFile];
NSLog(@"%@",outputString);`
```

But the output is nothing. Though, I am sure `NSTask` is getting executed. I think I am doing something wrong with `NSPipe`. But I am still not seeing the expected output.

Thanks.

Comment: How much output is your task generating?  If it's much at all, you need to deal with the fact that its output pipe fills up.  It's ridiculous – I have an open bug on Apple about it, for years – but there it is.